# Minimizing total variation

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of bounded variation. Define $\overline{f}(x)$ by 
$$\overline{f}(x) = \limsup_{\mu(I)\to 0} \frac{1}{\mu(I)} \int_I f(x) dx,$$ where  $I$ ranges over intervals containing $x$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. It is known that the total variation $|\overline{f}|_{TV}$ of $\overline{f}$ is minimal among those of all functions equal to $f$ almost everywhere; see, e.g., Lemma 3.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601044.pdf.

Now, that should be a very classical result. Does anybody have an older or standard reference?

Comment: $I$ is an interval, as I said clearly. $\mu$ is the standard Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you let $I$ range over open or closed intervals.

Comment: Oh as $I$ dimnishes, its still always be a neighbourhood of $x$?

Comment: Yes: "$I$ ranges over intervals containing $x$".